# Does Mirena IUD help with acne control too? Is it safe to take concurrently with Accutane?

Tags: acne, inter-uterine-device-iud, contraceptive, drug-interactions, accutane

If one to use the **Mirena IUD** contraceptive, **will it help with acne control too?**

Or should I take something separate for that? I'm due to see my dermatologist in awhile about starting **Accutane**, but she doesn't know about my recent decision to start **Mirena, are they safe to take together?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When someone is considering to take 2 drugs both of which can have severe side effects, he/she should discuss this with a doctor, so this part of the question CANNOT be properly answered here.**

Mirena can actually cause acne:

**1. Mirena side effects** ([Drugs.com](https://www.drugs.com/sfx/mirena-side-effects.html))

> The most commonly reported adverse effects are alterations of
> menstrual bleeding patterns, nausea, abdominal/pelvic pain,
> headache/migraine, dizziness, fatigue, amenorrhea, ovarian cysts,
> genital discharge, **acne/seborrhea,** breast tenderness, and
> vulvovaginitis
>
> Dermatologic side effects: **Very common...Acne/seborrhea (15%)**

**2. Mirena** ([Drugwatch](https://www.drugwatch.com/mirena/))

> Common side effects of Mirena include:
>
> - **Acne**
> - Weight change
> - Mood changes
> - Breast tenderness
> - Nausea
> - Ovarian cysts
> - Vaginal discharge
> - Abnormal bleeding patterns

**3. Mirena safety considerations** ([Mirena-us.com](http://www.mirena-us.com/safety-considerations/))

> Between 5% and 10% of Mirena users may experience:
>
> - Headache/Migraine
> - **Acne**
> - Depressed mood
> - Heavy or prolonged menstrual bleeding

**4.** Mirena contains the progestin hormone levonorgestrel, which can increase the blood levels of free testosterone (androgene hormone), which can cause acne ([AAD.org](https://www.aad.org/media/news-releases/hormonal-factors-key-to-understanding-acne-in-women)).

*Stumpf PG et al, 1981 Changes in physiologically free circulating estradiol and testosterone during exposure to levonorgestrel ([PubMed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6778889))*

> During treatment with d-Ng [levonorgestrel]...the % of testosterone
> increased to about 55% of the total.

**5.** There are many conflicting anecdotal reports of the effect of Mirena on acne online.